# Several issues in a page's javascript I'm trying to build, ignoring "If" statement and equation not working, VSCode not giving any errors

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, select, equation

I'm very new to javascript as you may be able to tell, I'm trying to create a function that will replace a piece of text with either 1 value or the result of an equation based on what is selected via a dropdown menu. I don't know if I'm just being dense and it's something small I messed up or if it's something more complex that I'm missing.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <label for="gval">G Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="gval" name="gval">
        <label for="sval">S Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="sval" name="sval">
        <label for="bval">B Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="bval" name="bval">
        <label for="dval">D Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dval" name="dval">
        <select id="Level">
            <option value="default" selected>1-18</option>
            <option value="1">Level 1</option>
            <option value="2">Level 2</option>
            <option value="3">Level 3</option>
            <option value="4">Level 4</option>
            <option value="5">Level 5</option>
            <option value="6">Level 6</option>
            <option value="7">Level 7</option>
            <option value="8">Level 8</option>
            <option value="9">Level 9</option>
            <option value="10">Level 10</option>
            <option value="11">Level 11</option>
            <option value="12">Level 12</option>
            <option value="13">Level 13</option>
            <option value="14">Level 14</option>
            <option value="15">Level 15</option>
            <option value="16">Level 16</option>
            <option value="17">Level 17</option>
            <option value="18">Level 18</option>
        </select>
        <span Id="HPVAL">640-247</span>
        <script>
        var e = document.getElementById("Level");
        function onChange() {
        var Result = BVALUE+GVALUE*((LVALUE-1)*((0.66+(SVALUE/100-0.05))+((1-(0.66+(SVALUE/100-0.05)))/17)*(LVALUE-1)))
        var LVALUE = e.value;
        var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var HPVALVAR = document.getElementById('HPVAL');
        var SVALUE = document.getElementById('sval').value;
        var GVALUE = document.getElementById('gval').value;
        var BVALUE = document.getElementById('bval').value;
        var DVALUE = document.getElementById('dval').value;
        const span = (HPVALVAR);
        if (LVALUE="default") {
            span.innerHTML = DVALUE;
        }
        else {
        span.innerHTML = Result;
        }
        }
        e.onchange = onChange;
        onChange();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The way it is meant to function:

it shows a default value you choose an option from the dropdown if the option is the default then it goes back to whatever the default text is supposed to be (I'm not sure how to store values away for later yet so I just have it connected to a text box which I manually enter the info into)
if you choose a value that isn't the default it runs an equation based on values in the other boxes and the value of the current dropdown option, it then replaces the span text with the results of that equation.

Comment: You should use `==` or `===`

Comment: `=` is a assignment operator and returns true in `if` statement

Comment: the == edit worked great, the equation stil seems to be broken though... it just shows "NaN" as the result.

Comment: that doesn't sem to matter, I have fixed it but regardless of if its's id or Id it does write to the correct place

Comment: I put at the bottom what I'm going to do with the code. The purpose for it is a dynamic stat block for video game characters. This one is for the health value. the equation is supposed to take all these values, put them through the equation, then spit out what the health value is at that level.

Comment: I have added the updated code in my answer, please have a look

Comment: In `onChange()` the first thing that happens is you try to use a whole pile of variables which don't exist - `BVALUE`, `GVALUE` etc. You need to define your variables before you can use them.  Also, what is `const span = (HPVALVAR);` supposed to do?  I'd suggest starting with some JS tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` for value or `===` for type and value comparison.
`=` is an assignment operator and returns true in `if` statement.

You can read more about it in the official doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <label for="gValue">G Value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="gValue" name="gValue"><br/>
  <label for="sValue">S Value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="sValue" name="sValue"><br/>
  <label for="bValue">B Value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="bValue" name="bValue"><br/>
  <label for="dValue">D Value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dValue" name="dValue"><br/>
  <select id="level">
    <option value="default" selected>1-18</option>
    <option value="1">Level 1</option>
    <option value="2">Level 2</option>
    <option value="3">Level 3</option>
    <option value="4">Level 4</option>
    <option value="5">Level 5</option>
    <option value="6">Level 6</option>
    <option value="7">Level 7</option>
    <option value="8">Level 8</option>
    <option value="9">Level 9</option>
    <option value="10">Level 10</option>
    <option value="11">Level 11</option>
    <option value="12">Level 12</option>
    <option value="13">Level 13</option>
    <option value="14">Level 14</option>
    <option value="15">Level 15</option>
    <option value="16">Level 16</option>
    <option value="17">Level 17</option>
    <option value="18">Level 18</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <p>RESULT: <b><span id="hpValue">640-247</span></b></p>

  <script>
    var levelElement = document.getElementById("level");
    level.addEventListener('change',
      function(e) {
        var levelValue = levelElement.value;

        var levelText = levelElement.options[levelElement.selectedIndex].text;
        var hpElem = document.getElementById('hpValue');

        var gValue = document.getElementById('gValue').value;
        var sValue = document.getElementById('sValue').value;
        var bValue = document.getElementById('bValue').value;
        var dValue = document.getElementById('dValue').value;
        var result = bValue + gValue * ((levelValue - 1) * ((0.66 + (sValue / 100 - 0.05)) + ((1 - (0.66 + (sValue / 100 - 0.05))) / 17) * (levelValue - 1)))

        levelValue == "default" ? hpElem.textContent = dValue : hpElem.textContent = result;
      })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that worked for the "If" statement but the equation still seems to be broken, it comes back as "NaN" as an answer. It's still not throwing errors...